# Traveling to India from USA with 2 laptops and an iPad

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, india, duty-free

I'm sure this question has been asked many times, but having gone through all the different answers, I'm more confused than ever before. I'm traveling to India from USA (point of entry: Delhi). I have a 7 year old Sony VAIO laptop purchased in India that is now slightly damaged, so I want to take it with me and keep it at home. Someone there might repair it for a much cheaper price (as compared to in USA) and use it.

Since my own laptop is damaged, I purchased a secondhand Dell laptop on eBay recently, and I want to take it with me for the duration of my stay in India. I am a university student in the US, and need this laptop for my thesis work. However, since this laptop was purchased here in US, I'm not sure if I'll be allowed to get it through in customs at India. I'll be returning only with this laptop (duration of stay: 5 weeks).

The price of the laptop purchased at eBay is $199, and I have the invoice for this. I don't have an invoice for the Sony VAIO laptop. (It's been 7 years!)

Other than this, I also have a Samsung phone and an iPad (both purchased in India), and an iPod purchased in USA. At the time of purchase, the iPad was about Rs 44000/$700–$800. It's a 3rd gen iPad, so as of now its valuation might be much lesser.

Which items can I carry without running into customs hassles in India?

Comment: To give you an answer in one word. Yes. Why? Because I've done the exact same thing without any issue. They opened my check-in luggage to check the old laptop, so make sure you have a bag with a TSA compatible lock.

Comment: @AdityaSomani So, as I understand it, you suggest that I put one laptop in my check-in baggage with a TSA approved lock, and the other laptop in my carry-on baggage, right?

Comment: @DarkKnight Yes. That's what I did previously and it worked out fine. :)

Comment: @DarkKnight As long you don't intend to cheat the system you'll be fine. Now, as far as I can see, you are fine. :)